# Why does model not connect with user?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model that appers in admin. But it doesn't connect with user automatically. I always have to specify user in admin. I have a form for creation. But when I create with this form it doesn't appear on the screen.

Models

```
class Notion(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='notions', null=True, blank=True)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
     def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('notions')
```

Views

```
class NotionList(ListView):
    model = Notion
    context_object_name = 'notions'
    template_name = 'base/notion.html'
      
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['notions'] = context['notions'].filter(user=self.request.user)
      

        search_input = self.request.GET.get('search-area') or ''
        if search_input:
            context['notions'] = context['notions'].filter(title__icontains=search_input)
        context['search_input'] = search_input

        return context

class NotionDetail(DetailView):
    model = Notion
    context_object_name = 'notion'
    
    template_name = 'base/notion_detail.html'

class NotionCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Notion
    form_class = NotionForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('notions')

class NotionUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Notion
    template_name = 'base/notion_update.html'
    fields = ['title', 'body']

class DeleteNotiontView(DeleteView, LoginRequiredMixin):
     model = Notion
     template_name = 'base/notion_confirm_delete.html'
     success_url = reverse_lazy('notions')
```

Forms

```
class NotionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Notion
        fields = ['title', 'body']
```

Urls

```
 path('notion/', NotionList.as_view(), name ='notions'),
    path('notion/<int:pk>/', NotionDetail.as_view(), name ='notion_detail'),
    path('notion-create/', NotionCreate.as_view(), name ='notion-create'),
    path('notion/update/<int:pk>/', NotionUpdate.as_view(), name ='notion-update'),
    path('notion/<int:pk>/', NotionDetail.as_view(), name ='notion'),
    path('notion/<int:pk>/delete', DeleteNotiontView.as_view(), name ='notion-delete'),
```

Comment: Can you include code for how you are creating and saving this Notion object? The user will have to be passed to it for there to be a connection.

Comment: Please include form code.

Comment: I've added views and urls and forms. I am a bit baffled actually because I never had such a problem